# How to perform rowttest in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns and 679 rows and a I need to perform a ttest using da function rowttest from genefilter package. A want list the two first columns with the other two.

```
A_R1   A_R2   B_R1    B_R2  
1       2       7      7
4       5       8      7.5
5       5       9      NA
6       5       10     NA
...
```

I used this code, but I not really sure what "fac" means. I thought it was the number of rows.

```
#t.test is the dataframe used
ttest2=na.omit(ttest)
rowttests(as.matrix(ttest2),fac=679,tstatOnly = FALSE)
```

I have this error:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rowttests’ for signature ‘"matrix", "numeric"’
```

or

```
Error in rowcoltt(x, factor(integer(ncol(x))), tstatOnly, 1L) : 
  Invalid argument 'x': must be a real matrix.
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument is meant to be a factor that indicates the groups (of columns) on which the t-tests are performed.

```
> m=matrix(runif(80), 20)
> rowttests(m, factor(c("M", "M", "F", "F")))
      statistic           dm     p.value
1    1.15567467  0.297622456 0.367224496
2    0.81334422  0.328723537 0.501449912
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The data cannot be a matrix of integers!!!

**BEFORE**

# x is a data.frame of INTEGERS here ...

```
x <- read.table("HFLF.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
g <- c("HF","HF","LF","LF")   
results<- rowttests(x, factor(g))
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘rowttests’ for signature ‘"data.frame",
>   "factor"’

# tried converting x from a dataframe to a matrix ...

```
x <- as.matrix(read.table("HFLF.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1))
g <- c("HF","HF","LF","LF")
results<- rowttests(x, factor(g))
```

> Error in rowcoltt(x, fac, tstatOnly, 1L) :    Invalid argument 'x':
>   must be a real matrix.

**AFTER**

# x is a dataframe of REAL numbers here (with decimal places) ...

```
x <- read.table("HFLF.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
g <- c("HF","HF","LF","LF")
results<- rowttests(x, factor(g))
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘rowttests’ for signature ‘"data.frame",
>   "factor"’

# tried converting x from a dataframe to a matrix ...

```
results<- rowttests(as.matrix(x), factor(g))
head(results)
```

I figured it out from something that "Joran" posted here:
http://w3facility.org/question/conversion-of-data-frame-to-matrix-error/

Comment: I mean the answer itself doesn't really help this particular question, but the error messages help to google it and made it very helpful to identify my own bug. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see?`rowtests`

> rowttests(x, fac, tstatOnly = FALSE) x     **Numeric matrix**  and fac **Factor**
>   which codes the grouping to be tested

here you give a matrix and a numeric, you must coerce teh numeric to a factor. So change

```
rowttests(as.matrix(ttest2),fac=679,tstatOnly = FALSE)
```

To

```
rowttests(as.matrix(ttest2),fac=factor(679),tstatOnly = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, but one of the problems are this error:

Error in rowcoltt(x, fac, tstatOnly, 1L) : 
  Invalid argument 'x': must be a real matrix.

I convert the data.frame in a matrix. I don´t understand

Comment: yes but I can't help because I don't see the definition of x in your question.

Comment: it is this your call : `rowcoltt(x, factor(integer(ncol(x))), tstatOnly, 1L)` ? or this is from the traceback? Also , did you test the first part of my answer , does this help you?

Comment: rowcoltt(x, factor(integer(ncol(x))), tstatOnly, 1L) Invalid argument 'x': must be a real matrix.

This is the error that appears after I perform your answer.